# Iterating objects in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the Error in the below code? I tried to iterate over the array of objects using the map. but I am receiving an error. Please find attached the code for reference.

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
const sample = [{
samplePath : "/website",
 par:{
  abc:"123",
  def: "678",
  ghi:"456"}
}];

const createURL = (re)=> {

const q = Object.entries(re.par)
    .map(([key, value]) => key +'='+value).join("&");

return "?"+ q;
}

console.log(createURL(sample));

return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
    <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
  </div>
);
}
```

I am receiving the following error
[image: error]

Comment: The sample is array, you are trying to access sample.par, that is incorrect do, createURL(sample[0])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to call `Object.entries` on `re.par`.  In this case, `re` is an array, so calling `.par` on it returns undefined.  I'm not sure what your desired result is, but if you access the first element in the array and then `.par`, maybe that's what you're after?

```js
const sample = [{
samplePath : "/website",
 par:{
  abc:"123",
  def: "678",
  ghi:"456"}
}];

const createURL = (re)=> {

const q = Object.entries(re.par)
    .map(([key, value]) => key +'='+value).join("&");

return "?"+ q;
}

console.log(createURL(sample[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example `sample` is an array, containing one object.

So, either, remove the [] such that sample is an object like you are referring to it in your code. Or, `Object.entries(re[0].par)`